# SKSpriteNode - create a round corner node?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

Is there a way to make a SKSpriteNode round cornered? I am trying to create a Tile likesqaure blocks with color filled SKSpriteNode:

```
SKSpriteNode *tile = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0
                                                                           green:128.0/255.0
                                                                            blue:255.0/255.0
                                                                           alpha:1.0] size:CGSizeMake(30, 30)];
```

How can I make it round cornered?

Thanks!

Comment: **Note** you may be better off, just making the image have transparent corners - https://stackoverflow.com/a/39983382/294884

Answer (score 53, accepted):

To get a rounded corner node you can use 2 approaches, each of them requires use of SKShapeNode.

First way is to use SKShapeNode and set its path to be a rounded rectangle like this:

```
SKShapeNode* tile = [SKShapeNode node];
[tile setPath:CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect(CGRectMake(-15, -15, 30, 30), 4, 4, nil)];
tile.strokeColor = tile.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0
                                                    green:128.0/255.0
                                                     blue:255.0/255.0
                                                    alpha:1.0];
```

The other one uses sprite node,crop node and SKShapeNode with rounded rectangle as crop nodes mask:

```
SKSpriteNode *tile = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor   colorWithRed:0.0/255.0
                                                                           green:128.0/255.0
                                                                            blue:255.0/255.0
                                                                           alpha:1.0] size:CGSizeMake(30, 30)];
SKCropNode* cropNode = [SKCropNode node];
SKShapeNode* mask = [SKShapeNode node];
[mask setPath:CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect(CGRectMake(-15, -15, 30, 30), 4, 4, nil)];
[mask setFillColor:[SKColor whiteColor]];
[cropNode setMaskNode:mask];
[cropNode addChild:tile];
```

If your tiles are one solid colour, i suggest you go with the first approach.

Comment: Even with SKShapeNode's current inconsistencies, the first method seems reliable and is pretty straight forward to implement.

Comment: SKShapeNode now has a 'rectOfSize:, cornerRadius:' initializer

Comment: If your tiles use textures, you can still go with the first approach, by setting the fillTexture of the SKShapeNode.

Comment: If you'd like to make the rounded rect one solid color, call `setSetStrokeColor:`

Comment: Note that the new cornerRadius initializer will crash devices running anything less than iOS 8. Shouldn't Xcode warn you of these issues?

Comment: I have to say, this is **just wrong**.  In any game engine, any system, if you want a round sprite, you just make it round, a line of code.  SKShapeNode is really unrelated here, it's for a totally unrelated problem.

Answer (score 22):

In Swift 3 you can create with:

```
let tile = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30), cornerRadius: 10)
```

Comment: How should I set the a physics body for this SKShapeNode?

Answer (score 8):

Hope this helps:

```
SKSpriteNode *make_rounded_rectangle(UIColor *color, CGSize size, float radius)
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    [color setFill];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:radius];
    [path fill];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:image];
    return [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is heavily inspired by the accepted answer, yet it uses a more readable way to create the `SKShapeNode` and also fixes the annoying pixel line around the crop. Seems like a minor detail, but it may cost someone a few minutes.

```
CGFloat cornerRadius = 15;
SKCropNode *cropNode = [SKCropNode node];
SKShapeNode *maskNode = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithRectOfSize:scoreNode.size cornerRadius:cornerRadius];
[maskNode setLineWidth:0.0];
[maskNode setFillColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[cropNode setMaskNode:maskNode];
[cropNode addChild:scoreNode];
```

Comment: Sorry to repeat myself, but honestly, for the sake of anyone googling here, you just don't do this!   You simply crop the PNG, it's that easy

Comment: @Fattie My answer is general and crops any node. I wasn't using PNGs and if I did, I surely wouldn't want to touch every single one of them. So it still has its value.

Answer (score 5):

## It's really this simple.......

```
class YourSprite: SKSpriteNode {

    func yourSetupFunction() {

          texture = SKTexture( image: UIImage(named: "cat")!.circleMasked! )
```

There's nothing more to it.

## You really *can not use* SKShapeNode.

It's just that simple. It's an insane performance hit using SKShapeNode, it's not the right solution, it's pointlessly difficult, and the purpose of SKShapeNode just has no relation to this problem.

[image]

Look at all them kitties!

The code for circleMasked is this simple:

(All projects that deal with images will need this anyway.)

```
extension UIImage {
    
    var isPortrait:  Bool    { return size.height > size.width }
    var isLandscape: Bool    { return size.width > size.height }
    var breadth:     CGFloat { return min(size.width, size.height) }
    var breadthSize: CGSize  { return CGSize(width: breadth, height: breadth) }
    var breadthRect: CGRect  { return CGRect(origin: .zero, size: breadthSize) }
    
    var circleMasked: UIImage? {
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(breadthSize, false, scale)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        
        guard let cgImage = cgImage?.cropping(to: CGRect(origin:
            CGPoint(
                x: isLandscape ? floor((size.width - size.height) / 2) : 0,
                y: isPortrait  ? floor((size.height - size.width) / 2) : 0),
            size: breadthSize))
        else { return nil }
        
        UIBezierPath(ovalIn: breadthRect).addClip()
        UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1, orientation: imageOrientation)
            .draw(in: breadthRect)
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }

// classic 'circleMasked' stackoverflow fragment
// courtesy Leo Dabius /a/29047372/294884
}
```

That's all there is to it.

Comment: Whilst this does circles well, and seems like you've walked through a series of glass walls to find this solution, how does this help make rounded rectangles as masks?

Comment: hi @Confused. I have no idea, at all, what you mean?  Can you explain what you're asking - I will try to help.

Comment: You've used a circle, which I often jokingly refer to as a fully rounded square. The OP is asking about rounded squares/rectangles. How would you do your magic upon a rounded rectangle/square? As the glass walls, I'm talking about how you're thought outside the framework to solve the problem.

Comment: hi @Confused - got you now.  fortunately it's easy to modify `UIBezierPath` to give rounded corners rather than "round".  i will try to put it in when I get a chance, but it is very easy: here's a great example by some excellent writer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41962342/294884

Answer (score 4):

### Swift 4:

A good solution could be created before you should add your sprite to his parent, I've maded a little extension that could be corrected as you wish:

```
extension SKSpriteNode {
    func addTo(parent:SKNode?, withRadius:CGFloat) {
        guard parent != nil else { return }
        guard  withRadius>0.0 else {
            parent!.addChild(self)
            return
        }
        let radiusShape = SKShapeNode.init(rect: CGRect.init(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size), cornerRadius: withRadius)
        radiusShape.position = CGPoint.zero
        radiusShape.lineWidth = 2.0
        radiusShape.fillColor = UIColor.red
        radiusShape.strokeColor = UIColor.red
        radiusShape.zPosition = 2
        radiusShape.position = CGPoint.zero
        let cropNode = SKCropNode()
        cropNode.position = self.position
        cropNode.zPosition = 3
        cropNode.addChild(self)
        cropNode.maskNode = radiusShape
        parent!.addChild(cropNode)
    }
}
```

### Usage:

```
let rootNode = SKSpriteNode(color: .white, size: self.size)
rootNode.alpha = 1.0
rootNode.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
rootNode.position = CGPoint.zero
rootNode.zPosition = 1
rootNode.name = "rootNode"
rootNode.addTo(parent: self, withRadius: 40.0)
```

Comment: great ! but my SKSpriteNode when i added radiusShape to it it wont center of mySKSpriteNode !

Answer (score 2):

from the class reference:

"An SKSpriteNode is a node that draws a textured image, a colored square, or a textured image blended with a color."

It seems the easiest way is to draw a block with rounded corners and then use one of these class methods:

- spriteNodeWithImageNamed:
- spriteNodeWithTexture:
- spriteNodeWithTexture:size:

Comment: +1: Sprite Kit is not a drawing API. It's an engine for managing the movement of predefined blocks of pixels (aka sprites).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Swift 3 snippet based on the second solution of the accepted answer.

```
func createPlayerRoundedNode(){
    let tile = SKSpriteNode(color: .white, size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
    tile.zPosition = 3
    tile.name = "tile node"
    let cropNode = SKCropNode()
    cropNode.zPosition = 2
    cropNode.name = "crop node"
    let mask = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30), cornerRadius: 10)
    mask.fillColor = SKColor.darkGray
    mask.zPosition = 2
    mask.name = "mask node"
    cropNode.maskNode = mask
    self.addChild(cropNode)
    cropNode.addChild(tile)
}
```