# How attach Particle Effect to a SpriteKit node in Xcode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, particles

I'm a begginer in xcode and i want
to make a Sprite Kit node with `BodyWithCircleOfRadius`, instead of creating a node with `SpriteNodeWithImageName`. How can I attach it to a particle effect?

thanks, ronen

Comment: The following sample might be useful to you .check Sprite Kit sample https://github.com/shu223/iOS7-Sampler

Comment: This is a related question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695305/skspritenode-create-a-round-corner-node/21695696#21695696?newreg=a33a1394443940be882cf8ef2e162bf5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SKSpriteNode technically cannot be a circle as its size is determined by CGSize (width,height). You can however attach a circular physics body using `bodyWithCircleOfRadius:` if you want. If you are looking for a particle effect, I would suggest you use SKEmitterNode instead.