# crop an SKSpriteNode to a rounded rect

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, geometry, skspritenode

i have searched up the net and found this answer on stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695305/skspritenode-create-a-round-corner-node)

the answer didn't quit satisfy what i want , maybe because  it was written in objective c .

i searched the net about how to circle a SKSpriteNode and didn't find an answer ,nevertheless 
here is some of the code i tried:

```
let cropNode = SKCropNode()
let mask = SKShapeNode()
mask.path(CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect(CGRectMake(-15, -15, 30, 30), 4, 4, nil));
// ↳ '(CGPath!)-> $T13' is not identical to 'CGPath'

cropNode.maskNode(mask)
// ↳ cannot convert the expression's type 'SKShapeNode'to type 'SKNode?'
cropNode.addChild(plate)
```

errors are shown as comments above.

i want to make my SKSpriteNode round cornered or in other words , make it a circle.
here is my declared SKSpritenode:

```
 var foodarea = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "plate")
```

this is the image that i want to circle ,and is shown [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ic8g0dinciwhdvb/plate.jpg?dl=0)

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use a PNG with transparent pixels rather than the JPG?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be confusing function call syntax with assignment syntax.

```
let cropNode = SKCropNode()
let mask = SKShapeNode()
mask.path = CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect(CGRectMake(-15, -15, 30, 30), 4, 4, nil)
cropNode.maskNode = mask
```

Comment: I have tried the above code , it doesn't work , it makes the sprite node disappear