# Use an SKShapeNode for the mask of an SKCropNode (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode, skcropnode

How can I use an `SKShapeNode` for the mask of an `SKCropNode`? My code currently creates an `SKShapeNode` circle and then sets the crop node mask to it

```
shapeNode = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50)
shapeNode.fillColor = UIColor.red
shapeNode.lineWidth = 1
shapeNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
shapeNode.zPosition = 4

cropNode = SKCropNode()
cropNode.maskNode = shapeNode
cropNode.addChild(Node)
```

But when I add the `Node` as a child of the cropNode it doesnt draw anything but a red circle (exactly as i set it to do)

Is there any way to use an `SKShapeNode` as the mask of an `SKCropNode`?

**-Update-**

I figured  out how to make an SKSpriteNode drawn from the SKShapeNode

```
shapeNode = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 60)
shapeNode.fillColor = UIColor.red

let shapeTexture = view.texture(from: shapeNode)
textureNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: shapeTexture)
textureNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
textureNode.zPosition = 3

cropNode.maskNode = textureNode
cropNode.addChild(tileMap2)
self.addChild(cropNode)
```

But now the SKCropNode isnt working when applied to the SKSpriteNode how do I fix this?

Comment: I remember this pain, but not the solution.

Comment: Here’s an answer I vaguely remember using the approach of, and getting it to work, I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39967815/crop-mask-circular-image-node-in-sprite-kit-gives-jagged-edges

Comment: Did you get the view?

Comment: Sorry for this dribbling out of comments... I'm trying to recall what I did whilst reviewing other answers. I think I had to draw (add) the skshapenode to a view and then get that view.

Comment: not sure why you are messing with the zPosition on your mask node,  I would get rid of that, other than that it should work fine

Comment: Man the udpate worked, thanks a ton